# Get number of object in a List with specific matching property in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, properties, count

I have a list of Animals like this :

```
 Animal : 
     int id;
     boolean carnivore;
     int leg;
```

In a function, i would like to retrieve, for instance, number of animals in that List which are carnivore (carnivore is true).

Instead of doing this :

```
  Integer nb = 0;
    for (Animal a : ListAnimal) {
        if (a.isCarnivore()) {
            nb++;
        }
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this ?
Thank you.

Comment: Not really in my opinion. You just have to loop and check like you just did. You wont discover anything better i suppose.

Comment: What does better mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java 8, use the `isCarnivore()` method as a `Predicate` to `filter()` a stream from the list, then call `count()`:

```
long nb = ListAnimal.stream().filter(Animal::isCarnivore).count();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an `int` for the `nb` variable rather than an `Integer`.

An alternative version in Java 8 is

```
long nb = ListAnimal.stream().filter(Animal::isCarnivore).count();
```